# Print/Obtain first character of a line in a text file in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix

Was wondering how you print/obtain the first character in a text file in unix.

i.e say "9 textfile.txt" would return 9

thx

Comment: It sounds like there's a larger problem you're trying to solve here...

Answer (score 8):

You can use `head` to get first char of file:

```
head -c 1 file.txt
```

---

If you want first char of every line:

```
grep -o ^. file.txt
```

Or

```
cut -c 1 file.txt
```

Comment: `head` will print the first character of the file and then stop. If you want the first character of each line use [`cut`](http://man.cx/cut).